# eagerloading with has_one association

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models i.e Question and choices like below

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :choices, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text
  belongs_to :question
end
```

here 3 or more choices for every question , in those 3 one is correct it stored in answer column in question table. i.e question.answer

**Question**: while I am displaying all questions I want to display choice text, it means correct answer(i.e ) `@choice Choice.find(@question.answer)` it will display `@choice.text` but it cause `n+1` problem.

can we implement this is with one query or eager loading like...?

View:

```
 %table
      %tr
        %th No
        %th Question  
        %th Answer
      - @review_questions.each_with_index do |question,index|
        %tr
          %td= index+1
          %td= question.text
          %td= question.answer
```

Comment: Actually I do not know how to use eager loading,can u explain? Example Question: text ,answer(it is one of the choice id)

Answer (score 1):

Eager loading is gathering all the required data at once use full in `n+1` situations

These will run two queries

1. Find all question
2. All choices for question for all question in one query and cache it

you can access the choices for each question by

```
@question.each do |question|
 choices = question.choices
 correct_choice = choices.detect{|choice| choice.id = question.answer}  
end
```

and find the choice of answer by

```
// return the choice with id @question.answer
```

More details on eager loading

http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

**Example how to Use**

Controller:

```
@questions = Question.all(:include=>:choices)
```

Question Model:

```
def correct_answer
   choices.detect{|choice| choice.id = self.answer}  
end
```

View: ( Sorry I am not that good at haml never tried it much rectify if anything wrong )

```
%table
  %tr
    %th No
    %th Question  
    %th Answer
  - @questions.each_with_index do |question,index|
    %tr
      %td= index+1
      %td= question.text
      %td= question.correct_answer.text
```

Comment: Actually i am finding bunch of questions like Question.find(:all)

Comment: check my updated answer, did you check the railscasts if not do it now :)

Comment: Hi, i am new to rails can u please mention what code, will place in model and how to access that variable in view.

Comment: %table
      %tr
        %th No
        %th Question  
        %th Answer
      - @review_questions.each_with_index do |question,index|
        %tr
          %td= index+1
          %td= question.text
          %td= question.answer

Comment: Thank you very much Pritesh , but it executes many times. example : If we have 10 questions , it will execute 20 times. Am I right ?

Comment: @DurgaPrasad It will only give 2 db calls and will run 10 times in loop if 10 questions

Comment: Thank you very much Pritesh, it helps in my current project.